# Word Document (2007) missing pages?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007

I was working on a Word 2007 document that was about 50 pages long. I don't know what I did, but now when I open the document, only the first 5 pages appear.

I tried emailing the file to my friends, and one person was able to view the file fully, but the rest were only able to view the first 5 pages. All machines are Windows 7 64 with MS Office 2007.

How can I recover the missing pages and fix the document?

Comment: this is a question for super user

Comment: Ask the person who's able to view the complete file to copy-paste the contents to a new document, save and send it over. Hopefully the copy will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

A theory, based on the very limited information available and presumably no possibility of further clarification, is that the 'invisible' text is present but was inadvertently set as white font colour. "The rest" were also not able to see the text because viewing it as formatted, whereas the one friend who was able to view the file fully was reading it as plain text. Any takers? :-)